# UK visa validity

Tags: visas, uk, visa-expiration

I have a UK visa and I am traveling to London. I will be in London up to May 20 and my visa ends on May 27. Am I eligible to visit London if my visa is expiring 7 days after my trip?

Comment: Yes you are. ..

Comment: You can use your visa until it expires. Just make sure you leave before it expires.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You may stay in the UK up to the end of the day the visa expires but it is OK to leave the UK many days or weeks before that.